# Запрос Where в Codeignither

Tags: php, codeigniter

Всем привет. Использвую фраймворк Codeignither.

Запись `$this->db->where('visible',1)`; аналагично `where=1`, 
а как написать запись аналагично `where>1`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

`$this->db->where('visible >', 1);`